# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 5 Failure/Error it {should have_selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm working on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (chapter 5) and I'm getting an error.  My code is at....

https://github.com/Hjack/sample_app_new

I'm getting the following error...

```
hakimus-MacBook-Air:sample_app_new hakimujackson$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
...FFFFFF

Failures:

  1) Help page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1',   text: 'Help')}
       expected css "h1" with text "Help" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Help page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help'))}
       expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) About page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1',  text: 'About')}
       expected css "h1" with text "About" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) About page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us'))}
       expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Contact page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1',   text: 'Contact')}
       expected css "h1" with text "Contact" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Contact page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title',  text: full_title('Contact'))}
       expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.21916 seconds
9 examples, 6 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:20 # Help page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:21 # Help page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:28 # About page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:29 # About page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:36 # Contact page
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:37 # Contact page
```

Here is my spec.rb file...

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do

    subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do

    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',  text: 'Sample App')}
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title(''))}
    it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home'}
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',   text: 'Help')}
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help'))}
    end


  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',  text: 'About')}
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us'))}
    end


  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path}

    it { should have_selector('h1',   text: 'Contact')}
    it { should have_selector('title',  text: full_title('Contact'))}
    end
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your spec file --

```
describe "StaticPages" do

subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do

    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',  text: 'Sample App')}
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title(''))}
    it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home'}
  end
end
```

You are ending the rspec context too soon -- move the last 'end' to the bottom of your spec, and your tests should all pass.

cheers!